# Android MediaPlayer release problem (bug?)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Playing various http music media streams (radiostations), a release problem is sometimes encountered in that a new stream will not start until approx 30 seconds later.

The release sequence explained at developer.android.com is:

mediaPlayer.release();
mediaPlayer = null;

After this, upon preparing a new stream, the logcat sometimes says:

E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer could not be located....

This behaviour is indicative of the MediaPlayer NOT being properly released, so that a new one may not be started immediately (the normal working case), but will have to wait on some (assumed) GarbageCollection or similar in the MediaPlayer.

We have alternatively tried mediaPlayer.reset() and then mediaPlayer.prepare(...)… but with the same catastrophic result.

Any suggestions to sidestep this problem will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your device platform doesn't support QCMediaPlayer. See this Github link to understand properly

https://github.com/fallowu/slim_hardware_qcom_media/blob/master/QCMediaPlayer/com/qualcomm/qcmedia/QCMediaPlayer.java

You can use soundpool....

Comment: Yes, it does support QC. Most of the time no problem. One can observe that on logcat. It LOOKS like a release problem on the http stream.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, this is clearly a bug in the release process of the mediaPlayer. Occassionally, the mediaplayer gets stuck in its native part (=QC), and the only way to release from this superbig disaster is to clear the cache of the app. Obviously a highly unsatisfactory solution.

We are using LG phones, and it could of course be something with that brand. Hope Android team reads this. The solution should involve a return value true/false from the release process, unless they are able to find a more waterproof solution.